# Is there alternative to avant browser in linux to open java applet?

Tags: linux, java

I have an oracle forms website and is based on java and I used to open the web page in windows with Avant browser but I didn't find an alternative for in Linux , I can't open the java applet with firefox I don't know is there any plugin to do that in firefox
so my question how can I open the java applet in Linux , is there in firefox a plugin or something to render a java web page or there is an alternative to Avant browser in linux ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer ? Part of JDK

Comment: thank you @ArtemS.Tashkinov for your answer but I'm having trouble with making it work can you show me some steps

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers stopped supporting Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface (NPAPI) a while ago, which is the technology that you need for Java applets.

However, the [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/) browser seems like an option. In their future roadmap they make this statement:

> *"Pale Moon supports NPAPI plug-ins. Unlike Firefox, we will not be deprecating or removing support for these kinds of plug-ins. This
> means that you will be able to continue using your media,
> authentication, and other plug-ins in Pale Moon like Flash,
> Silverlight, bank-authenticators or networking plug-ins for specific
> purposes."*

I haven't personally used this browser, but I hope this helps.

Comment: this is definitely helpful but unfortunately, I still can't open my URL  with pale moon and this is the URL hope someone help me http://oraapp.mutah.edu.jo:8889/forms/frmservlet?config=teacherapp